# Misc information HTML element attributes

Tags: html

I've been using `rel` to store some non-html information, what other attributes are not commonly used that I can utilize to store information?

Comment: This is dangerous stuff. The Rel attribute is actually pretty widley used i.e. Google bot amongst other things uses it.

It's not advisable to use defined HTML attributes for your own purposes.

Comment: @Chris: All this stuff is generated by a chunk of JavaScript, nothing anyone should be reading.

Comment: .then there is no need to store your data in an attribute owned by someone else. Just because you can't see a collision coming doesn't mean you are guaranteed not to have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to switch to HTML5 and use [custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Comment: Before HTML5 came out with this, I've always used _something as attribute names for custom data, under the assumption that it's very unlikely a real attribute will begin with an underscore. Is this an "acceptable" assumption, or would I be better off switching everything to data-something?

Comment: I'd recommend using `data-*`, because it's then valid HTML into the bargain.

Comment: I'll use this, thanks. I'm using jQuery's `attr` function so a native JS implementation isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5 you can define your own `data-` attributes to store whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can make up your own attributes if you wish. It is probably not a good idea to put data into an attribute if by specification it should have something meaningful in there.

Answer (score 2):

This help? Scroll down to the rel section:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/semantics.html

Answer (score 2):

In the [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), you can use `data-*` attributes; they're guaranteed not to do anything with the browser and they'll work in older browsers, too.

In JavaScript, you can access it with the normal attribute properties:

```
var value = elem.getAttribute("data-foo")
elem.setAttribute("data-foo", "value")
elem.removeAttribute("data-foo")
```

With new browsers you can use `elem.dataset`, but you probably don't want to do that as older browsers won't support it.

```
var value = elem.dataset.foo;
elem.dataset.foo = "value";
elem.dataset.foo = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 now [supports](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) storing information in data-* attributes but thats HTML5 and everyone isn't there yet. So a real world scenario...

If you don't have to worry about persisting across post backs you could map simple data objects as a JSON collection var and pull an object out of it based on a particular key. But that is a broad approach - more information on the overall goal would improve the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of information you're looking to store and how are you planning on accessing it. I successfully used both the `id` and the `class` attributes to store and access database IDs for example, and even references for some database tables, which I then retrieved with jQuery to do some AJAX requests.

If you are NOT using HTML5, I would advise against using your own custom attributes. Otherwise, like people already suggested before me, have a look at the `data-` prefixed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

data-* is the way to go if you can use HTML5. You can easily access them in javascript too with elem.data.*

Otherwise, custom attributes are probably better than screwing up the semantics of the page.